# http-proxy-middleware proxy is not working in React js and Spring Boot project. GET API is return 415 status error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, proxy, http-proxy-middleware, http-status-code-415

I'm using the **http-proxy-middleware** middle ware. Content-Type: application/json is must be add in API's headers while execute with postman. I added my API's header configuration in React.

I think the error is caused by I dont send headers corrently. Actually I dont know. Please help me.

Thanks

**Spring Boot**

MovieController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private IMovieService movieService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/fetchAllMovieList", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> fetchAllMovieList() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(movieService.fetchAllMovieList(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**React**

movieAction.js

```
import {API_BASE} from "../config/env";
import axios from 'axios';

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

export function fetchMovies() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_MOVIES",
            payload: axios.get(`${API_BASE}/movie/fetchAllMovieList`, {
                headers: headers
            }).then(response => console.log("Action/moviesAction.js -> response -> ", response))
        })
    }
}
```

setupProxy.js

```
import {API_BASE} from "./env";
const createProxyMiddleware = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        createProxyMiddleware("/movie/fetchAllMovieList",{
            target: `${API_BASE}`,
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    );
};
```

env.js

```
export const API_BASE = "http://localhost:8080";
```

Results in Console

```
GET http://localhost:8080/movie/fetchAllMovieList 415
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 415
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

Results in Network

```
{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-04T07:24:51.116+00:00",
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "message": "",
  "path": "/movie/fetchAllMovieList"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I and Mahdi solved that problem. We missed **data:{}** part. I added under the **headers: headers,** and mixed him and mine codes. I'm going to share solition.

moviesAction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    Accept: "application/json"
}

export function fetchMovies() {
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await axios.get(`/movie/fetchAllMovieList`, {
            headers: headers,
            data: {}
        });

        console.log("Action/moviesAction.js -> response -> ", response);

        dispatch({
            type: "FETCH_MOVIES",
            payload: response.data,
        });
    }
}
```

setupProxy.js

```
import {API_BASE} from "./env";
const {createProxyMiddleware} = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use("/movie/fetchAllMovieList",
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: `${API_BASE}`,
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    );
};
```

env.js

```
export const API_BASE = "http://localhost:8080";
```

Add proxy in package.json

```
  "name": "movie-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  **"proxy":"http://localhost:8080",**
  "dependencies": {
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked more closely at the code and noticed many mistakes. This is true.

env.js

```
module.exports = {
  API_BASE: "http://localhost:8000",
};
```

add this to package.json

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:8000",
```

setupProxy.js

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware"); // import module
const { API_BASE } = require("./env");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/movie/",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: API_BASE,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

movieAction.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  Accept: "application/json",
};

export function fetchMovies() {
  console.log("action run...");
  return async (dispatch) => {
    console.log("async action run..");

    const response = await axios.get(`/movie/fetchAllMovieList`, {
      headers: headers,
    });

    console.log(response.data);

    dispatch({
      type: "FETCH_MOVIES",
      payload: response.data,
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment  but unfortunately result is still same. I was execute this one "npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware". I deleted 
related section in package.json and I executed this one"npm install http-proxy-middleware --save". And I changed setupProxy.js like your comment

Comment: Now try to go to api like this; http://localhost:3000/movie/fetchAllMovieList. API is return 404 now
I wonder if setupProxt doesn't work ? I gave localhost 8080 port in that class

Comment: I searched some web sites. We was should add  `data: {}` under the `headers: headers,` I mixed your and mine codes I'm going to comment final situation and close this question. Thank you so much

Comment: OK. Glad I helped you.